# Can I use this example for binding energy

Tags: binding-energy

From what I understand, no particles are converted to energy during a nuclear reaction. Could I use the following analogy?:

4 billiard balls are rolled into a bowling ball one at a time. Each billiard ball causes the bowling ball move 1 centimeter so the bowling ball has moved 4 centimeters after being impacted by 4 billiard balls.

Next the 4 billiard balls are somehow compacted into a single mass and rolled into the bowling ball but this time the bowling ball only moves 3 centimeters.

Anything wrong with this analogy?

I came up with this analogy because I think that the mass of sub-atomic particles is determined by the trajectories of debris after collisions. This is very different from the notion of weighing something on a scale.

Comment: How does your analogy apply to binding energy?  I don't see how it helps to illustrate what binding energy is or how it works.

Comment: Not so much to explain binding energy but to demonstrate the conservation of particles and to dispel the notion, which many people believe, that particles get converted to energy. The billiard ball / bowling ball analogy comes about because I believe that atomic and sub-atomic masses are measured by  making collisions and analyzing trajectories.